# Is downloading multiple files officially supported by Salesforce in lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, files, contentversion, support

The url "hack" to use /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ has been documented in a salesforce blog about visualforce pages showing images, however I can't find anywhere where this is officially supported by salesforce.

Does anyone know if this is actually supported or just a hack?

Edit: Currently, the only way I've found to download multiple files (or all files for a specific record) is to create a link to {salesforce-base-url}/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{id-of-contentversion}/{id-of-second-contentversion}? etc.

However, I have only found the use /sfc/servlet.shepherd/ to be documented is here : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/04/building-content-rich-visualforce-pages-with-salesforce-crm-content.html

However, this is only for visualforce.

I want to use this in a client's Lightning Record Detail Page.
So, the question I'm asking is, 'Is this "feature" officially supported for Lightning, or is it documented anywhere?'

Comment: Its not very clear as what you are asking. Could you edit your question and provide more details?

Comment: I have edited my post. Please let me know if this is clearer. I suppose it's not a common issue.

Comment: Why haven't you tried using the url on a lightning page?

Comment: I have. I've put lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ and it still works. 
I'm just asking if using this within client code is supported by salesforce.